# How to solve? "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again."?

Tags: xcode4

I go to organizer. I press

Devices

Then I go to editor and Refresh from developer portal.

I got this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.
```

So I deleted all certificate or anything xcode related from my keychain. I deleted all certificate from apple developer center. Same problem.

Then I do it again.

First xcode says that there is no certificate. Want to make one. Sure.

Certificate is indeed created.

Then I got that message `An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.`

It seems that I need to have some code signing identity. But how to make that and where is it? It's not available in itunes connect or apple developer program support.

I thought my certificate is my identity.

There is a similar question already. It says to delete both in Apple developer center and in xcode. I did that. It doesn't work.

Sometimes I got a message whether I want to sign with  Looks like some key is wrong. But what?

When I tried to run a program I got:

(null):  Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

When I go to organizer and submit my application to create that distribution certificate I got No identities available for signing.

So I download identities. Then I got an error occurred while attempting to download. Please try again.

There is also an option saying

Import developer profile. I guess I have to recreate this so called developer profile. What is it? And how?

According to this, after I create my first certificate I will be asked if I want to create a developer profile.

That never happens. I just got "An unexpected error occured" again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xcode 5, I solved this  by refreshing my provisioning profiles in preferences - accounts.

Hope this works for you.